# Merge SQL table data to an existing SQL table with the same column names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

I have two tables one with all the parts numbers (ITEMNO) and another with COMMENT4.

I have another table with the same names but it only has a few ITEMNO from the first list.

If I run this query I get

```
insert into dbo.icitem (comment4)
select COMMENT4 
from dbo.f1$ 
where dbo.icitem.ITEMNO = dbo.f1$.ITEMNO)
```

I get this error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> The multi-part identifier "dbo.icitem.ITEMNO" could not be bound.

I want to insert `comment4` from `F1$` to `comment4` from `icitem` when `ITEMNO` is the same.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please clarify the tables structure? And also I didn't catch how many tables do you have two or three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple issues:

```
where dbo.icitem.ITEMNO = dbo.f1$.ITEMNO)
```

This line is a problem, ITEMNO doesn't have a place in this context. In practice you should be joining the table and doing an update.

Something similar to this should suit your needs according to my understanding:

```
UPDATE item
SET item.COMMENT4 = f.COMMENT4
FROM dbo.icitem item
    JOIN dbo.f1$ f
        ON f.ITEMNO = item.ITEMNO
```

This will compare both data sets and then only update rows in icitem where itemno matches between it and the f1$ table

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you need to use update operation instead of insert:

```
UPDATE dbo.icitem
SET comment4 = f1.comment4
FROM dbo.icitem inner join dbo.f1 on icitem.itemno=f1.itemno
```